# remove a self vote to a question

Tags: support, reputation, answers

is possible remove self vote to an answer without give point or remove? 
I'm explain better the question, for example I give to an answer **+1** and the **user take 10 point**, but then i want to remove it if i press **-1** the **user loss 2 point** and i have value of answer **0**, **finally him take 8 point**, i want remove my vote like that i don't give him point, this is possible?

Comment: Click the upvote arrow again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click the orange up-arrow again to cancel your upvote. After some time goes by, though, your vote will be locked in and you won't be allowed to cancel it (until and unless the post is edited) -- so hurry up!

Comment: thanks men I accept you answer in few mins

Comment: It'll be locked in *until* the post is edited. :-)

Comment: Indeed, I shall add that detail.